# Numpy:Getting row number of element which have maximum value at n'th column in the matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix

Let's say our matrix be:

```
#alternatives
a1="4 1 0 1 0"
a2="5 1 0 1 0"
a3="6 0 0 1 0"
a4="7 1 1 0 0"
a5="6 0 0 1 0"
a6="3 0 1 1 0"
a7="7 1 1 0 1"
import numpy as np
dm=np.matrix(a1+";"+a2+";"+a3+";"+a4+";"+a5+";"+a6+";"+a7)
```

I want to get **row number** of **maximum value** of 5'th column.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Row number can be retrieve by this way:

```
sq=dm[:,4]
print(np.where(sq==np.max(sq)))
```

Result is like this:

```
(matrix([[6]]), matrix([[0]]))
```

6 is row number of element which have maximum value at 5'th column.